# How to read a GeoPoint once and then go back to normal view?

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, osmbonuspack

I'm totally new to android development, I used [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) in creating an app for Android, I want to get a point by clicking on the map and I found this solution :

```
MapEventsReceiver mReceive = new MapEventsReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public boolean singleTapConfirmedHelper(GeoPoint p) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),p.getLatitude() + " - "+p.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(p.getLatitude(),p.getLongitude());
        // This is the line i will explain in problem #2
        Global_point = point;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean longPressHelper(GeoPoint p) {
        return false;
    }
};
MapEventsOverlay OverlayEvents = new MapEventsOverlay(mReceive);
mapView.getOverlays().add(OverlayEvents);
```

by this [page](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5), and I put it in `Onclick` function of a Button.

The problems are:

1- It (point receiving) Won't stop and it will run forever, How can I stop it when a GeoPoint got received?

2- The MapEventsReceiver is an Interface that should implement as it defined, so `singleTapConfirmedHelper` function should return a Boolean, How can I return the GeoPoint that got received by clicking? I know I can define a Global variable and fill it in singleTapConfirmedHelper-function but I am asking if it is possible to change the Interface-function return value.

**Ps**: I know i can remove the map overlay by indexing:

```
mapView.getOverlays().add(0,OverlayEvents);
mapView.getOverlays().remove(0);
```

but I don't know where should I put it.

Comment: It seems to me, that you might be new to programming (and Java) in general, not just to Android (and that's fine, don't worry). 
How did you integrate this functionality into your application? Are you using new activity with MapView? Or Fragment? Or some kind of dilaog? Ad #1 Think more about when the interaction should be ended. Is there a button for user to close/cancel? Is the user supposed to use native back button? Or do you need some kind of delay and finish it automagically? Ad#2 You cannot change the return type of method in an interface, but it wouldn't help you at all.

Comment: @JosefAdamcik ,yes as i said, there is a Button there, when user push it,he or she select a location on the map so later i can route to there.

Comment: Ok, I see, sou you are staying on the same screen. You actually need to call some function, pass to ti the point. This function will remove overlay and store the point somewhere/ use it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You should call some methot from singleTapConfirmedHelper. It's anonymous class so it can call methos of the class where it's created.

```
MapEventsReceiver mReceive = new MapEventsReceiver() {
    @Override
    public boolean singleTapConfirmedHelper(GeoPoint p) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),p.getLatitude() + " - "+p.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        onPointSelected(point);
        return true;
    }
//...
}
```

And later, somewhere in your Activity or Fragment:

```
private void onPointSelected(GeoPoint p) {
    //do whatever you want with the point. For example: store it in a field
    this.selectedPoint = p;
    //finish interaction => somehow remove or turn of particular overlay
    mapView.getOverlays().remove(0);
}
```